# .htaccess - 301 redirect with no query string, leave as is if query string

Tags: .htaccess

I put in a 301 redirect for my `/index.php` as recommended for SEO purposes. Unfortunately this prevents any params being accepted.

- `example.com/index.php` should redirect to `example.com`
- `example.com/index.php?anything` should stay at `example.com/index.php?anything`
- `example.com/index.php?f=bar&b=foo` should stay at `example.com/index.php?f=bar&b=foo`

My attempted fix is below:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It looks like you attempted fix should only cause your rewrite rule to happen when there is no query string.   It is similar to the accepted answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/84258/how-do-i-redirect-index-php-only-when-there-is-no-query-string   Are you saying that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s\/index\.php\s
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteRule . http://${HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer for the scenario is a combination of Deadooshka's answer and a POST fix.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s\/index\.php\s
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```